# Are post banned users eligible to post on a per-site Meta

Tags: support, post-ban, per-site-meta, meta

Given one of the most common duplicate posts on the current Meta Stack Overflow deals with "Why can't I ask questions" (or to a lesser extent, "why can't I post answers"), I am curious about how the upcoming MSO/MSE split will change the user experience for post banned users.

Currently, post banned users can post on Meta Stack Overflow since it is the defacto Meta Stack Exchange and has no minimum rep requirement.  But how does it work with a true per-site meta?  Does the post ban extend to the per-site meta as well, or can users ask about their ban and get support on that meta (assuming they meet the minimum rep requirements of a per-site meta)?  What about users who don't meet that minimum rep?

In most cases, the users asking these questions are not worthy of a lot of attention or feedback (nor do the want it, they are usually just ranting about being banned and demanding we release it), but occasionally, you do encounter a user who seems to have a desire for real feedback and you want to provide some support.

A secondary question is what support should we be providing?  Are questions about the post-ban for a specific site going to be on-topic for MSE, or should we be sending them to the new MSO (or appropriate per-site meta) to get feedback on their posts?

Comment: My understanding is that you need 5 rep to post on a per-site meta.  Post bans on the main site should have no effect on one's ability to post to a meta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Appealing post bans *is* on topic on per site metas (it's just not accepted when you haven't even tried on your end). Post bans do not extend to per site metas: I have seen an answer banned user posting answers on meta, and [here is a question banned user posting a question on meta.](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6945/why-was-i-banned)

Note that the 5-rep requirement still holds for posting on meta. In the extremely rare case where an incorrectly post banned user with <5 rep needs to appeal, they can use the contact us form or appeal on MSE.

Comment: `Appealing post bans is on topic on meta`, I was specifically asking about which meta.  If such questions show up on MSE, it would seem that they would be better asked on MSO.

Comment: @psubsee2003 per site. Fixed. I guess MSE can be used if the rep requirement prevents you from using MSO, but it's better to use the contact us form instead.

Comment: So, when MSE is live, all "i am not post question why ban?" crap goes there?

Comment: @AmalMurali No, it goes to MSO. Where most will be closed.