# Does a post ban on some site affect MSE, and vice versa?

Tags: support, meta, post-ban

I want to know whether we will be banned on Meta Stack Exchange when we have a ban on a Stack Exchange site itself.

If someone gets the message

> We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account.

on Stack Overflow, they are banned from Stack Overflow. But are they then also banned on MSE? And if I'm banned from MSE, will I be banned from SO as well?

Comment: This is related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: @rene That I know. I was just asking whether it affects other Stack acounts. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, a question or answer ban on Meta does not affect your accounts elsewhere, and vice versa.

Your account here is entirely separate, because meta.stackexchange.com is a special, separate site. The thresholds for the question and answer bans are also **much harder** to trigger on MSE, because usage and voting patterns are very different here, and in most cases, you would have been contacted by a moderator before getting banned.

Note that a post ban doesn't extend to per-site metas either; if you are question banned on Super User, you can still post on Meta Super User to ask for help. See [Are post banned users eligible to post on a per-site Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213940/are-post-banned-users-eligible-to-post-on-a-per-site-meta)